# Get last 5 records from each ID without using LIMIT

Tags: sql, postgresql, excel, vba

I have the following SQL code I use in Excel VBA importing data from PostGreSQL:

```vb
Const sqlconnection = "Provider=visoledb;"

Dim conn As New Connection
conn.ConnectionString = sqlconnection
conn.Open
Dim rs As Recordset

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "FR"
Sheets("FR").Select
Range("A1").Select

DIm fr As String
    fr = "SELECT master_id, eventdate, num_result " _
    & "FROM fr INNER JOIN person p ON fr.master_id=p.entity_id AND p.auditflag=1 " _
    & "WHERE fr.auditflag=1 AND num_result IS NOT NULL AND num_result <> 0 " _
    & "ORDER BY master_id "  

Set rs = conn.Execute(fr)
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Refresh
End With

rs.Close
```

which gives me all the record values for each person in the table.

I have been informed that I cannot use `LIMIT`, so how can I restrict it to only show me the last 5 records for each person.

Comment: Which column is used to order the records ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT master_id, eventdate, num_result 
FROM fr INNER JOIN
     (SELECT p.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.entity_id ORDER BY ?? DESC) as seqnum
      FROM person p
     ) p
     ON fr.master_id = p.entity_id AND p.auditflag = 1 AND seqnum <= 5
WHERE fr.auditflag = 1 AND num_result IS NOT NULL AND
      num_result <> 0
ORDER BY master_id;
```

I don't know how you define "last 5".  The column that specifies it is what `??` refers to.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a normalized database of one-to-many joins with distinct *Persons* having multiple *fr* records and the need *show me the last 5 records for each person* indicates a time element so suggests the `fr.eventdate` field, consider Postgres' [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html) window function.

Specifically, this `ROW_NUMBER()` calculates an order of records grouped by the foreign key, `f.masterid` (i.e., each person id) by descending `eventdate`. With such a rank, you can then filter for top 5 in the  `WHERE` or `ON` clause of the outer query:

```sql
SELECT t.master_id, t.eventdate, t.num_result
FROM 
    (
     SELECT fr.master_id, fr.eventdate, fr.num_result, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fr.master_id ORDER BY fr.eventdate DESC) AS rnk
     FROM fr
     WHERE fr.auditflag=1 AND fr.num_result <> 0 AND fr.num_result IS NOT NULL
    ) As t

INNER JOIN person p
   ON t.master_id = p.entity_id AND p.auditflag=1 
WHERE t.rnk <= 5
ORDER BY master_id, t.eventdate;
```